# Stop a recursive function which uses setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, async-await, cancellation

I have the following template in my project:

```js
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function foo (x) {
  await sleep(3000)
  await asyncTask()
  await foo()
}
```

It should repeat the job (`foo`) **until** a specific event is received. However, I am having a hard time finding a way to stop the recursion. Seems like there is no way to achieve it with this approach.

In some other, I could not find an answer/comment to describe how to terminate this kind of function.

One potential way would be using `setInterval` with an async function, but seems like `setInterval` is supposed to work with sync callbacks only.

(I've seen there are some npm packages for this particularly, but I am trying to avoid adding a new dependency just for this)

---

**Edit:** Seems like this solution also works:

```js
let timeoutId

async function loop (socket) {
  await asyncTask()

  timeoutId = setTimeout(
    async () => await loop(socket),
    3000
  )
}

socket.on('event', () => clearTimeout(timeoutId))
```

Comment: How is the "event" received? Can you access to the event from the function `foo`?

Comment: @SantiagoRojo Yes, I can. It is a socketio client that receives and handles events.

Comment: `asyncTask` doesn't seem to use the return. Perhaps it should? Then you probably wouldn't need `sleep`.

Comment: Do you need to cancel the promises if the event happens?

Comment: @SantiagoRojo I need this cron task to refresh a specific token before it expires periodically unless the client disconnects. On the `disconnect` event, I need to stop refreshing the token.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Does my previous comment clarify the situation a bit more? I may have abstracted my use case in the wrong way in the post.

Comment: `if (Istillwanttocontinue) await asyncTask(); if (Istillwanttocontinue) await foo();`

Comment: Your latest approach would not work if the event occurs while `await asyncTask()` is awaiting because there would be no timer running yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual mechanism is to check some flag that can be set from the outside:

```
// outside code watching for some event can set this flag to true
// to stop further recursion
let stopRecursion = false;

function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function foo (x) {
  await sleep(3000)
  await asyncTask()
  if (!stopRecursion) {
      await foo()
  }
}
```

Or, this can be built into an object passed to `foo()` to make it a more self-contained implementation:

```
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function foo (x, options) {
  await sleep(3000)
  await asyncTask()
  if (!options.stopRecursion) {
      await foo(x, options)
  }
}
```

And, the outside code can set `options.stopRecursion` to `true` when it wants the recursion to stop.

---

In case you're wondering, Javascript doesn't have any mechanism from outside the function to cancel the recursion.  So, you have to build some test into the recursion itself (checking a variable, property or some external state) and then you can mutate that state when you want it to stop recursing.

---

An object oriented approach, would make `foo()` be a method on an object and you could then have another method on the object called `cancelRecursion` that would set a boolean on the object that foo would check before recursing.  So, there's lots and lots of ways to structure this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and insights! I have also updated the description with another approach.

Comment: Instead of a custom object, you could use an `AbortController` that can also be passed to Web APIs, and comes with nice other features.